# Telegram API: get file id

Tags: telegram

The file id I get in telegram API is like this (the message is a media message containing a media file, look for id and access_hash):

```
msg:  (message (ID: 0xc09be45f) = (out=True, mentioned=None, media_unread=None, silent=None, post=True, id=13, from_id=None, to_id=(peerChannel (ID: 0xbddde532) = (channel_id=123456)), fwd_from=(messageFwdHeader (ID: 0xc786ddcb) = (from_id=None, date=2017-06-19 12:36:06, channel_id=123456, channel_post=1234)), via_bot_id=None, reply_to_msg_id=None, date=2017-06-26 01:51:33, message=, media=(messageMediaDocument (ID: 0xf3e02ea8) = (document=(document (ID: 0x87232bc7) = (id=580320036828xxxxxx, access_hash=2107500923xxxxxx, date=2017-02-01 03:16:25, mime_type=video/mp4, size=988xxx, thumb=(photoSize (ID: 0x77bfb61b) = (type=s, location=(fileLocation (ID: 0x53d69076) = (dc_id=4, volume_id=42992xxxx, local_id=69xx, secret=89375067683695xxxxx)), w=90, h=90, size=2409)), dc_id=4, version=0, attributes=['(documentAttributeVideo (ID: 0xef02ce6) = (round_message=None, duration=10, w=480, h=480))'
```

However the file_id which seems to be the right format is expected to be looking like this:

```
AgADBAADL6gxG06L8w0nhNO87UW3iZTKmxkABJtAM4jAZAfxxxxxx
```

So I am wondering do I need to convert the id and access_hash to get the file_id and what would be the formula, or why I don't see the file_id in the full hex format?

Comment: you can't do anything with the files from other chats! file_id will be assigned to files after you send the file to your bot. id, access_hash can be used in telegram clients to send them(as a user and not as a bot)

Comment: I can do everything with the file using telegram api. My issue is with the bot api file_id format. Apparently there is a formula to convert the file_id, secret and volume_id to the hex format, or even better telegram api itself might have a function to do the conversion.